# Sorting a list returns original sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list based on the sequence of a second list. My method currently is as follows:

```
letters = ["m", "h", "a"]
order = ["h", "a", "m"]
sorted(letters, key=lambda letters: order.index(letters[0]))
print(letters)
```

Instead of sorting `letters` to be the same as `order` (the second list), it leaves `letters` unchanged. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: `it instead outputs in a random order every time`. I can't replicate this with the code you have provided.

Comment: This prints `['h', 'a', 'm']`? Is that not what was intended? Perhaps you meant `sorted(letters, key=lambda letters: order.index(letters))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To correctly sort by the indicies of `order`, you need to do this:

```
sorted(letters, key=lambda letters: order.index(letters))
```

Using `letters[0]` in this case also works, since the strings are only length 1, but is not needed when you can call `letters` itself.

However, since calling `index()` is **O(N)**, a better approach would be to store the indices in a reveresed dictionary mapping:

```
sort_map = {e: i for i, e in enumerate(order)}
sorted(letters, key=lambda x: sort_map[x])
```

Which ensures that the order lookup is **O(1)**.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @RoadRunner's answer, don't need to call index manually, and no need slow `lambda`, do it automatically!!!

So do:

```
sorted(letters, key=order.index)
```

Same thing for adding to @Shayn's answer, do:

```
letters.sort(key=order.index)
```

Comment: Ah nice. Missed `key=order.index`.

Answer (score 0):

```
letters = ["m", "h", "a"]
order = ["h", "a", "m"]
letters = [x for x in order if x in letters]
print(letters)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.